# Perl: Scanning body text for URIs and remove using URI::Find::Simple

Tags: perl, uri

I'm trying to scan the article text in a joomla database for URIs that result in a 404. If a 404 is found, remove the anchor and just leave the resulting text.

The code below succeeds in locating the URIs, but I have no idea how to then strip them out of the body text, leaving just the text portion of the link.

The fetch_body() function returns a pointer to the article, where the id, fulltext, and other characteristics can be accessed.

I've also experimented with HTTP::Tiny to download the URL and check the status and it appears to work properly.

Is there an existing module I can use to strip the URL, leaving only the text? Can URI::Find:Simple be used to return the entire HTML (anchor?) surrounding the URI?

I don't know what more information I can provide to help me determine what to do next.

```
  foreach my $ref (fetch_body($dbh)) {
     print "checking body: $ref->{'id'} ";
     my @uris     = URI::Find::Simple::list_uris($ref->{fulltext});
     foreach my $uri (@uris) {
        print "current uri: $uri\n";
        # check uri for status code here ***
        my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->get($url);
        if ($response->{success}) {
             print "status: $response->{'status'}\n";
        } else {
             print "Failed: $response->{status} $response->{reasons}\n";
        }
     }
  }
```

These other two functions just open the database and return a pointer to the article in the joomla database.

```
  sub db_connect() {
  my %DB        = (
    'host'  => 'db.example.com',
    'db'    => 'db5',
    'user'  => 'joomla',
    'pass'  => 'joomlapass',
   );

   return DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$DB{'db'};host=$DB{'host'}",$DB{'user'}, $DB{'pass'});
   }

   sub fetch_body ($) {
   $dbh  = shift;

   my $sql       = "select id, title, alias, urls, \`fulltext\`
                 FROM xxx_content
                WHERE state     = 1";
   my $sth       = $dbh->prepare($sql);
   my @rv        = ();

   $sth->execute();

   while (my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
      push @rv, $ref;
   }
   $sth->finish();
   return @rv;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM qw( );

sub check_url {
   my ($url) = @_;

   # Replace with code to check of the URL is reachable.
   return $url !~ /non-existant/;
}

# From your database or whatever.
my $html = '
   <body>
       <p><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></p>
       <p><a href="http://www.non-existant.com/">Bad</a></p>
   </body>
';

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);

for my $ele ($dom->find('a[href]')->each) {
   my $url = $ele->attr('href');
   if (!check_url($url)) {
      delete $ele->attr->{href};
   }
}

$html = "$dom";    

print $html;  # Do whatever you want with the modified HTML.
```

Comment: Would you describe a bit more about what that's doing? What should I adjust "/non-existant/ to be? I'm not sure of its purpose. Do I substitute my article ($ref->{fulltext}) for the <body> text you have in your new() example?

Comment: You would pass the HTML you want to modify to `Mojo::DOM->new`. I passed a hardcoded string as a demonstration